# replace a string 6 line after matching string

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to change notification_interval from 15 to 2 for block File_Check only.

I tried changing line 6th after matching File_Check line with:

```
sed -e '6 /File_Check/ s/15/2/g' file.txt
```

but it did not work.

Here is file.txt:

```
define service {
    host_name                       local
    service_description             Memory
    check_command                   check_nrpe
    max_check_attempts              3
    check_interval                  5
    retry_interval                  1
    check_period                    24x7
    notification_interval           15
    contact_groups                  test
    notification_period             24x7
    notifications_enabled           0
    notification_options            w,c
    _xiwizard                       nrpe
    register                        1
    }

define service {
    host_name                       local
    service_description             File_Check
    check_command                   check_nrpe
    max_check_attempts              3
    check_interval                  5
    retry_interval                  1
    check_period                    24x7
    notification_interval           15
    contact_groups                  test
    notification_period             24x7
    notifications_enabled           0
    notification_options            w,c
    _xiwizard                       nrpe
    register                        1
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/File_Check/,/contact_groups/ s/\(notification_interval\s*\)15/\12/g' file.txt
```

This will start in a row matching "File_Check" and end in a row matching "contact_groups" and will replace a "15" by "2" when "notification_interval" is in that row before the "15".

Answer (score 3):

Using `perl` is another alternative:

```
perl -p00 -e 'if (/File_Check/) {s/(notification_interval\s*)15/${1}2/}' file.txt
```

The `-00` option tells perl to read its input in "paragraph mode", blocks of text separated by blank lines.  The `s///` operation is applied only to the paragraph containing `File_Check`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative logic in `sed`:

```
sed -e '/File_Check/{
          :loop
          /notification_interval/!{
            N;
            b loop
          }; s/\(notification_interval\s*\)[0-9]\+/\12/
        }' your_file
```

**Explanation**

When you match `File_Check`, keep reading new lines and adding them to the pattern space until you match `notification_interval`. When you match it, make the regex substitution you need. The substitution I choose here is to substitute `notification_interval\s*[0-9]\+` (`notification_interval` followed by any amount of white space then at least one digit) with `\1` followed by 2. Now `\1` means whatever was captured inside the parens `\(...\)` in the regex; in our case, that's `notification_interval\s*`.

So essentially, this looks for `notification_interval` followed by any amount of whitespace then a group of digits and it replaces the group of digits with `2`.

Comment: where do i make the substitution for changing notification_interval 15 to notification_interval 2 ? also get this error sed: -e expression #1, char 88: unterminated address regex

Comment: @Quay My bad. The backslashes at the end of the line were unnecessary. I removed them and added some explanation about the regex substitution. Hope this helps.